# "Ebay.com" randomly not working inside network

Tags: networking, router, http, domain, www

Before I go to the work of calling my ISP I decided to see if this community has an answer.
I have never had this issue before, and I also haven't done any hardware or firmware changes recently.

So randomly this morning the domain "ebay.com" will not work. I can go to my history though and pull up something random that's "inside" that domain, like an item I visited yesterday, and that will pull up, but I can't get the main domain to load. Any ideas?

- I've tried the site on my smart phone's 4G and that works but not when it's on wifi.
- We have over 10 computers and I've tried some of them at random.
- I've tried explorer and chrome.
- I've tried rebooting our router.
- I tried both google and opendns servers.
- And as suggested I ran ip config /flushdns then restarted my browser.
- I also tried all three of the ebay.com domain address's

Here's the commands I ran

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\jayson>ipconfig /flushdns

Windows IP Configuration

Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.

C:\Users\jayson>nslookup ebay.com
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    ebay.com
Addresses:  66.211.160.87
          66.211.160.86
          66.135.216.190

C:\Users\jayson>

Comment: Best bet to start is open Cmd as administrator and type "ipconfig /flushdns", this clears your local DNS cache (the thing you computer checks before asking around to find where a website is) and is always the first thing to do when you think you might have a DNS issue.

Comment: tried this with no avail. appreciate the thoughts though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ebay.com is hosted on multiple servers (presumably load balanced). Perhaps one of the 3 servers is misbehaving?

```
$ nslookup ebay.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Server:  dns.tb.iss.as9143.net
Address:  212.54.40.25

Name:    ebay.com
Addresses:  66.211.160.86
          66.211.160.87
          66.135.216.190
```

Looks like ebay is down http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/ebay.com.html

```
Website Name: www.ebay.comURL 
Checked: no response
Response Time: ~9 hours 51 mins
Down For: Ebay.com is DOWN for everyone.
```

Perhaps the entries from your history were cached?

See [Reports of an eBay Outage While Company Remains Silent](http://www.ecommercebytes.com/C/blog/blog.pl?/pl/2014/7/1406807196.html)

Comment: I tried all three of these address's separately. Same results though. It works on my 4G but not in my network. appreciate the thoughts.

Comment: Actually if I even google, lets say, "ebay camera" and click on a link that's inside the ebay.com domain it works, just literally not the "ebay.com" domain, but thanks for the link. It's good to know it's probably something on there end instead of something I need to fix. Seems a little weird though it works fine still on my phones 4G.